# How to add html after wrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with html and I don't know how to solve it... I created a code that wrap this line

```
<div class='new'></div>
```

For example, the code that was like this:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

Turns

```
<div class='new'>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

After that I want to add a new code after `</div>` but I dont know how to do it!

I tried `$("input").wrap("<div class='new'></div>").after("<button></button>")` but it add after input like this:

```
<div class='new'>
    <input type="text"/>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

And I want this:

```
<div class='new'>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
<button></button>
```

Can you help me to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("input").wrap("<div class='new'></div>").parent().after("<button></button>")
```

Explanation: the wrap tag counter intuitively returns the input element again, so we call parent to navigate to the top of div.new.  From there, when we invoke the .after it will append the HTML to the correct area.

Comment: thank you so much, I was using children haha but worked now! Thank

Comment: Hey, could you upvote and mark as answer, that would help a lot.  And you're welcome !